# How to post data from ionic to restfull api (Codeigniter)?

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter, typescript, ionic3

I have a problem to post data from ionic 3 to restfull api using codeigniter, i don't know why, I have looked for example in google but failed all.

This is Restfull api (codeigniter):

```
public function create_user() {
    $data = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id', TRUE),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE)
    );

    $query = $this->model_user->create_user($data);
    if($query == false) {
        $outputData = (object)array(
            'status' => false,
            'msg' => 'Register Failed',
            'redirect' => null   
        );
    }else{
        $outputData = (object)array(
            'status' => true,
            'msg' => 'Register Success',
            'redirect' => 'home'  
        );
    }   

    $this->output($outputData);     
}
```

This is myscript (Ionic 3):

Profile.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ResProvider } from '../../providers/res/res';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public resProvider: ResProvider) {
  }

  registerForm() {
      this.resProvider.postRegister()
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
          });
  }

}
```

res.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ResProvider {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello ResProvider Provider');
    }

    postRegister() {
        let params = {
            'id': 11,
            'name': 'frank',
            'email': 'frank@gmail.com'
        };

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.post('http://localhost/api/user/create_user', params)
                .subscribe(res => {
                    resolve(res);
                }, (err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Please anyone help me to solve this problem, 2 days again I must collect this duty to my lecture.

Thanks.

Comment: And what issue are you having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I don't get error in console, but data cannot send to php/codeigniter @user184994

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code where you're calling `postRegister` then please?

Comment: @user184994 I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

```
postRegister() {

  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("id", "11");
  form.append("name", "frank");
  form.append("email", "frank@gmail.com");


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post('http://localhost/api/user/create_user', form,{headers:headers})
            .subscribe(res => {
                resolve(res);
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}
```

> this.http.post('http://localhost/api/user/create_user', form)

**codeigniter defulty accept only form data**

Comment: Thanks, it works well, but I must add 'let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});'

Comment: Great to hear. If you really found my solution useful to you then please Up-vote & Mark as a Solution.